# Charting the sum of two Prometheus data source values in Grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am trying to create a chart in Grafana with Prometheus data source which includes a series indicating the total size of the young gen memory used on a java 8 jvm.  Below is the formula I have used to sum the values together:

```
(jvm_memory_pool_bytes_used{job="jmx",instance=~"my-jboss-server:10191",pool="PS Eden Space"}
+ 
jvm_memory_pool_bytes_used{job="jmx",instance=~"my-jboss-server:10191",pool="PS Survivor Space"})
```

I am able to chart the individual values for `PS Survivor Space` and `PS Eden Space` but as soon as I try to add them together, there is no data returned.

Below is some sample data which is returned:

```
jvm_memory_pool_bytes_used{pool="PS Eden Space",} 5.83346368E8
jvm_memory_pool_bytes_used{pool="PS Survivor Space",} 8.5090432E7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sum() function. It would probably look something like

```
sum(jvm_memory_pool_bytes_used{pool=~"PS Eden Space|PS Survivor Space", [other labels]})
```

For more info check Prometheus Querying [Basics](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/).

Comment: That does not work - I can see it is returning values in the query inspector but there is no line in the chart for these values.

Comment: There appears to be some kinda a bug where the chart does not work.  Tried the exact same query and it worked.